# Chrome slow from home network

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I have a very strange issue. Two days ago, suddenly Chrome started being very slow. Loading a web page with pictures (so, all of them) takes many, many minutes. Doing the same thing from IE or Edge is fast.

What makes this issue even stranger is that this happens from three different computers. I have disabled all chrome addins, tried Chrome on a computer that never have had Chrome installed etc. but no luck.

Disabling Wifi and using the built-in 4G modem works like a charm. Also tried an ethernet cable, but same issue there.

I guess the only common part is the network, but how no earth to troubleshoot something like this?

Marius

Comment: That is a weird one. Im speculating fairly wildly (but am possibly qualified to do so) - I wonder if the issue relates to a compatibiliy with HTTP/2 and your router (maybe its implementation of NAT?)

Comment: Another possibility could be IPV6 on the router - see the end of the thread at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=440381 which describes a similar, but not identical problem.   Maybe its a bug with IPV6 and MTU ?

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, today the issue have magically fixed itself. No changes made to anything, chrome still same minor build etc.